# yammer in a multiple networks scenario: the global admin does not become yammer admin

Tags: administration, yammer

I am in a situation where we need to keep separate yammer networks. On the main one connected with me as a global admin everything works. If I create a dummy user for the other domains and make them global admin in order to see them as yammer network admins I get the exact same situation: the user is a normal user and does not become a yammer network admin.

I have already called microsoft but they simply tell me its random and the best chances are to create a user with no licence and to never assign a yammer licence, which I have done already 3 times.

I have tried to create the user via cloud only and even via ad on premise to later synch it with O365. Nothing has changed. The user(s) are always normal users.

Anybody tried what I am trying to achieve successfully? what exact steps have you performed?

Comment: Did you try to assign the user as a yammer admin on this page? https://www.yammer.com/<yourdomain>/admin/set_admins

Comment: that page in my secondary networks gives me "Network admins can delete content, remove members, invite guest users, and configure security settings. The current admins are:" and nothing underneath and no button to add a user

Comment: The exact result to the link you posted is 'You've hit a 404 page, but keep believing!'

Comment: Are you still believing?!! :) did you set the user as global admin via azure ad?

Comment: I have set the user as global admin via O365 (which for me is the only way I can set up a global admin)

Comment: are you the admin for the other network?

Comment: I am admin for the 'main' network. This one I am working on is a secondary network of a secondary domain of another internal business unit

Comment: 1. https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Frequently-asked-questions-Yammer-activation-guide-4f6763f4-23e2-43b0-a554-08931295e863 2.https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Network-migration-Consolidate-multiple-Yammer-networks-a22c1b20-9231-4ce2-a916-392b1056d002

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Frequently-asked-questions-Yammer-activation-guide-4f6763f4-23e2-43b0-a554-08931295e863

**My company has multiple domains and I want to activate Yammer Enterprise for all of them. How do I do that?**

Office 365 supports **one** activated Yammer Enterprise network per account. If your organization has multiple domains, start by activating your home network using the domain that accommodates the majority of your users. Then, you can **work with Support** to add your additional domains to your home network. Note that you need to verify these domains in Office 365.

**How do I make someone a Verified Admin in Yammer?**

Office 365 and Yammer admin functions are currently managed separately. There are two ways to make someone a Yammer admin:

If someone is made a Global Admin in Office 365 and added to the **matching** contoso.com domain, they are automatically made a Verified Admin in Yammer. This can be done at the time of activation or later. Once someone is a Global Admin, the only way to remove them from being a Verified Admin in Yammer is to change their Office 365 admin status to something other than Global Admin. You cannot change their admin status in Yammer.

You can appoint someone to be a Network or Verified Admin within Yammer, without making them an Office 365 Global Admin. Their admin status is controlled completely within Yammer, and they have access only to Yammer admin features.